# Generic Return Type

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to write a class which provides me decrypted values for any given domain model. The following logic works fine, but don't know what to declare in the place of `XXXXXX`.

Sample Domain Model:

```
public class emp
{
    public string empname{get;set;}
}
```

I will call the `DecryptByObject` method something like:

```
var x = DecryptByObject(emp,KEY);
```

`DecryptByObject` Method:

```
public XXXXX DecryptByObject(XXXXXX myObject, string decryptKey)
{
    Type t = myObject.GetType();       

    foreach (MemberInfo mi in t.GetMembers())
    {
        try
        {
            if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                string value = ((PropertyInfo)mi).GetValue(myObject).ToString();
                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                var decryValue = MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes, decryptKey);
                ((PropertyInfo)mi).SetValue(myObject, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryValue));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

    return myObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like as below.

```
public T DecryptByObject<T>(T myObject, string decryptKey)
{
    Type t = myObject.GetType();
    PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty("Items");
    object list = prop.GetValue(myObject);

    foreach (MemberInfo mi in t.GetMembers())
    {
        try
        {
            if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                string value = ((PropertyInfo)mi).GetValue(myObject).ToString();
                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                var decryValue = MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes, decryptKey);
                ((FieldInfo)mi).SetValue(myObject, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryValue));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }


    return myObject;
}
```

Comment: Why ignore the exception?

Comment: I do have exception handling mechanism, but for this issue context i've removed that part. @John Saunders

Comment: Then just remove the try/catch from the code you posted. You're confusing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public T DecryptByObject<T>(T myObject, string decryptKey)
```

As a side point, you want to add some error checking here as `prop` could well be `null` or an error may be thrown:

```
Type t = myObject.GetType();
PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty("Items");
if (prop == null)
{
    // handle this error...
}

object list = prop.GetValue(myObject);
```